# Murrine engine on GTK3?

Tags: linux, gtk

I'm trying to use a GTK theme which requires the Murrine engine, so I installed `gtk2-engines-murrine` from `apt-get`. It works fine in most apps, but some such as `nm-applet` segfault as soon as I try to load them, which is presumably because they're GTK3. How can I get the Murrine engine to work for GTK3 apps?

Answer (score 0):

So far as I know, the murrine engine is exclusively for GTK2 apps, and you will not be likely to ever get GTK3 apps to function with it (unless you have an interest in porting it).

Rather, there is a different engine for GTK3 called unico. If you wish to use GTK themes with GTK3 apps, you'll need the unico engine.

Comment: Note that there seem to be issues with the unico engine. I can confirm that I get segmentation faults with some themes, and several bugs were reported on that same issue.